# What type should I use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a result coming from a method that is either of kind TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult or SLComposeViewControllerResult.

I need to pass this to a method. Something like

```
[self doSomething:result];
```

How do I declare this method?

```
- (void) doSomething:(SLComposeViewControllerResult) result ?

- (void) doSomething:(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult) result ?

- (void) doSomething:(NSNumber *) result ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make two different methods that handle each. Each enum is a different type and should be treated as such. You can also forward the result on, using a boolean if you are just indicating success, or your own custom enum if you need more information.

```
- (void)doSomethingSL:(SLComposeViewControllerResult) result
{
   // made up, idk what the result enum would be be
   [self doSomething:(result == SLComposeSuccess)];
}

- (void)doSomethingTweet:(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult) result 
{
   // made up, idk what the result enum would be be
   [self doSomething:(result == TWTweetSuccess)];
}

- (void)doSomething:(BOOL)success
{
}
```

If you are still convinced that you want to handle them in a uniform way and ignore types, you could always cast the results to an int in the method and forward them on.

Answer (score 1):

Both SLComposeViewControllerResult and TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult are both enums, with 0 meaning cancelled and 1 meaning done.

So any of these should be OK:

```
- (void) doSomething:(SLComposeViewControllerResult) result;
- (void) doSomething:(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult) result;
- (void) doSomething:(NSInteger) result;
```

[edit] Note this comment in TWTweetComposeViewController.h:

```
// This class has been  deprecated in iOS 6. Please use SLComposeViewController (in the Social framework) instead.
```

So you should just use the SLComposeViewControllerResult version.

Comment: Not without warning, especially if protocols are involved.

Comment: No, it doesn't produce any warnings for any of them.

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting the numbers could be the same but how did you discover they were NSIntegers? Anyway I have to support iOS 5 on this app, this is why I am using TWTweetComposeViewController.

Comment: In XCode, hold the Cmd key down and click on a variable or a type. You will be taken to where it was defined.